# .strip won't remove last quotation mark in Python3 Program

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, input

EDIT: UPDATE, so I ran this with @Alex Thornton's suggestion.

This is my output:

```
'100.00"\r'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "budget.py", line 48, in <module>
    Main()
  File "budget.py", line 44, in Main
    budget = readBudget("budget.txt")
  File "budget.py", line 21, in readBudget
    p_value = float(maxamount)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 100.00"
```

Under Windows though, I just get the list of numbers, with the qutations and the \r's stripped off.

Now, I don't know too much about the way Windows and Linux handle text files, but isn't it due to the way Windows and Linux handle the return/enter key?

So I have this code:

```
def readBudget(budgetFile):
    # Read the file into list lines
    f = open(budgetFile)
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    budget = []

    # Parse the lines
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        list = lines[i].split(",")

        exptype = list[0].strip('" \n')
        if exptype == "Type":
            continue

        maxamount = list[1].strip('$" \n')

        entry = {'exptype':exptype, 'maxamnt':float(maxamount)}

        budget.append(entry)

    #print(budget)

    return budget

def printBudget(budget):
    print()
    print("================= BUDGET ==================")
    print("Type".ljust(12), "Max Amount".ljust(12))

    total = 0
    for b in budget:
        print(b['exptype'].ljust(12), str("$%0.2f" %b['maxamnt']).ljust(50))
        total = total + b['maxamnt']

    print("Total: ", "$%0.2f" % total)

def Main():
    budget = readBudget("budget.txt")
    printBudget(budget)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    Main()
```

Which reads from this file:

```
"Type", "MaxAmount"
"SCHOOL","$100.00"
"UTILITIES","$200.00"
"AUTO", "$100.00"
"RENT", "$600.00"
"MEALS", "$300.00"
"RECREATION", "$100.00"
```

It is supposed to extract the budget type (school, utilities, etc) and the max amount.  The max amount is supposed to be converted to a float.  However, when I run the program, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "budget.py", line 47, in <module>
    Main()
  File "budget.py", line 43, in Main
    budget = readBudget("budget.txt")
  File "budget.py", line 22, in readBudget
    entry = {'exptype':exptype, 'maxamnt':float(maxamount)}
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 100.00"
```

Shouldn't the strip function in readBudget remove the last quotation mark?

Comment: Your program works fine for me.

Comment: This is a CSV file: why don't you use the `csv` module? It will take care of almost all the processing you're doing here in one or two lines.

Comment: also fine for me, there might exists some issues with your txt file ;)

Comment: What does `repr(list[1])` returns?

Comment: Figured it out.  

I was executing it with Python 2.7 rather than Python3. -_-

Comment: @user1768884: I used Python 2.7 as well and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: That's really strange.  Any idea why it wouldn't like my Python 2.7?  I'm speculating an issue with the txt file.

Comment: @user1768884: is there any possibility that the code is not what we're seeing here? One example: perhaps you have two versions of the file, and were running the wrong one with Python 2.7 but the right one with 3? To satisfy our curiosity, could you try copying and pasting the exact code you show here to a brand new source file, and running it with Python 2.7 on your budget.txt file?

Comment: This is the exact same code.  There is only one file.

Nevertheless, I copied and pasted this code to a new source file, and I got the same error when I ran it with Python 2.7.

Comment: Ashwini's question seems like the right one-- if you had `$100.00"\r\n`, for example, this is what you'd have seen (in Python 2, anyway.)

Comment: Another interesting note.  I'm a dual-boot machine, and when I booted into Windows and tested this code on its Python 2.7, I had no errors. 

Wonder if it has something to do with Fedora's Python 2.7 configuration, or the way that Linux and Windows handle text files differently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried this:

```
>>> attempt = '"$100.00"'
>>> new = attempt.strip('$" \n')
'100.00'
>>> float(new)
100.00
```

I got exactly what one would expect- so it must be something to do with what we cannot see from the file. From what you've posted, it's not clear whether there is something subtly wrong with the string you're trying to pass to `float()` (because it looks perfectly reasonable). Try adding a debug `print` statement:

```
print(repr(maxamount))
p_value = float(maxamount)
```

Then you can determine exactly what is being passed to `float()`. The call to `repr()` will make even normally invisible characters visible. Add the result to your question and we will be able to comment further.

---

**EDIT:**

In which case, replace:

```
maxamount = list[1].strip('$" \n')
```

With:

```
maxamount = list[1].strip('$" \n\r')
```

That should then work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in this:

```
maxamount = list[1].strip('$" \n\r')
```

Or more specifically, the \r, removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to capture either all or most of the floating point info in a string.

Consider:

```
import re

valid='''\
123.45"
123.
123"
.123
123e-16
-123e16
123e45
+123.45'''

invalid='''\
12"34
12f45
e123'''

pat=r'(?:^|\s)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)'

for e in [valid, invalid]:
    print
    for line in e.splitlines():
        m=re.search(pat, line)
        if m:
            print '"{}" -> {} -> {}'.format(line, m.group(1), float(m.group(1)))
        else:
            print '"{}" not valid'.format(line)
```

Prints:

```
"123.45"" -> 123.45 -> 123.45
"123." -> 123 -> 123.0
"123"" -> 123 -> 123.0
".123" -> .123 -> 0.123
"123e-16" -> 123e-16 -> 1.23e-14
"-123e16" -> -123e16 -> -1.23e+18
"123e45" -> 123e45 -> 1.23e+47
"+123.45" -> +123.45 -> 123.45

"12"34" -> 12 -> 12.0
"12f45" -> 12 -> 12.0
"e123" not valid
```

Just modify the regex to capture what you consider a valid floating point data point -- or invalid.